# Azure Web App Service and Azure Web App Service Plan dissappeared but Web App still exists

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

At the end of Nevember 2018 I have created an Azure Web-App. For a static HTML page.  Complete with app service and app service plan. And I created FTP access data for the site back then.

Now I want to activate an authorization by Azure AD. Only users from my Azure AD should be allowed to view the page. And for this I have to change settings in the App Service. The app still exists. In Azure Active-Directory I can still see it under App-registrations. The HTML page is still available at the URL created at that time (https://[name-of-app].azurewebsites.net). The FTP access data still works.

[image]

But the app service created back then and the app service plan used have disappeared. I cannot configure the app anymore. I cannot change the App Service Plan anymore. The app does not appear in any resource group either. I also do not remember deleting the App Service.

How do I get the App Service and the App Service Plan of the Web App back?

I am the owner of the Azure Subscription and I am the Global Admin of the associated Azure AD.

Comment: Did you look for it in the correct subscription?

Comment: Have you tried getting it trough [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest) or [Azure Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/get-azwebapp?view=azps-3.8.0)?

Answer (score 0):

> In Azure Active-Directory I can still see it under App-registrations.

The first thing I want to clarify is that [applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/trusted-application-api/docs/registrationinazureactivedirectory) under **App registrations** is not the same thing as azure web app.

If you can still access https://[name-of-app].azurewebsites.net, the webpp should exist. Please check if you have select the correct subscription if there are more than one.

[image]

Then try to search the webapp again in the search box.

[image]